# init() inside custom cell class that is delegate and datasource of collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, init

Im really confused trying to init() some stuff inside my custom cell class that i want to be the datasource and delegate of a collectionview.

How do i init() so that i have the data in an array ready to be used by cellForItemAt??

```
var partArray : [CollectionStruct] = []

init(partArray: [CollectionStruct]) {
super.init(partArray: [CollectionStruct])


    innerCollectionView.delegate = self
    innerCollectionView.dataSource = self
    //innerCollectionView.tag = item

    // add some stuff from local sql lite to array
    // this is how i normally do this in viewDidLoad
    // but cant use that in cell subclass
    BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Part", delegateSender: "DownloadPack", completeBlock: { (result) in
        if result.isEmpty == false {
            self.partArray = result
        }
    })
}
```

If i just do:

```
init() {
// stuff for the array
}
```

I get swift suggesting i include this block:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: You can't create a custom initialiser. You need to implement the required initialisers and provide some other function to load your data.

Comment: just assign the data before reloading your cell object collectionview.

Comment: I don't follow what this means.. where is the data reloaded from in this case?  If the cell is the datasource for the nested collectionView the data needs to be assigned here?

Comment: @Paulw11 what are the required initialisers?

Comment: `init(coder)` and `init(frame)` but you don't need to override those. You will need to add an additional function to set the data and call that after you create the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create your own initializers for the UITableViewCell. The only two initializers you can override are one that recieves a frame (`init(frame)`) and one that recieves a code (`init(coder)`).

In order to find a solution for your problem, you can a use either a property or a method in which recieves the data array. Either one would be called or set after the cell is created. You make your setup, and afterwards you call `reloadData()` of the collectionView.

If you decide to use a property, you could do this mentioned logic in the `didSet` of the property.